# Windows Dll with Cross Compiled Dll

Tags: windows, dll, cross-compiling, dllimport, mingw32

I have a windows dll (Main application directly loads this windows dll) that links to another 2 dlls, which are obtained by cross-compiling using mingw32.

I am facing a weird problem with this linking.

Say I have 2 functions in first cross compiled dll funcA_firstdll() and funcB_firstdll()
and similarly I have 2 functions in second cross compiled dll funcC_secdll() and funcD_secdll(). 
When linking with windows main dll I dont get any linker errors but the dlls are not getting loaded.

So if I check the dependencies of windows dll using dependency walker I see both the first and second cross compiled dll in red colour.

When I click on first cross compiled dll I am seeing the functions present in that dll(funcA_firstdll() and funcB_firstdll() ) as green and second cross dll(funcC_secdll() and funcD_secdll()) as red.
Similarly When I click on second cross compiled dll I am seeing the functions present in that dll (funcC_secdll() and funcD_secdll()) as green and first cross dll as red.

I am unable to understand why are they unable to interlink with each other.
Is there any different way to link cross compiled dll's.

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,

Techtotie.

Comment: Solved it by myself. It was actually a problem with proxy libs generated by mingw were not interpreted properly by MSVC. So had to generate the def files also. Follow this tutorial http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself.

It was actually a problem with proxy libs generated by mingw were not interpreted properly by MSVC.

So had to generate the def files also. Follow this tutorial

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs